# This Riley Riddle is No Big Deal

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, affix-riddle

> My prefix is a hearty meal,
>
> My suffix tells you what is real.
>
> My infix points to the ceil,
>
> I've a brain that needs to heal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are

> Stupid (no big deal :))

My prefix is a hearty meal,

> Stu --> stew

My suffix tells you what is real.

> id (for identification)

My infix points to the ceil,

> up

I've a brain that needs to heal.

> Goes without saying :)